# Unix command to search multiple pattern in same file

Tags: unix

I need to search a  pattern p1  in a file and if that pattern is not found then I need to search another pattern p2 in same file.how can I achieve this using Unix command??

Comment: Welcome new contributor. Please, post sample data with the expected output and you must've tried something, post that too.

Comment: I have answered your question (as you are a new contributor and might be donwvoted for this), for the future, read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and whenever you ask a question be sure it is a minimal, reproducible example with input and output **AND** last but not least, provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can also be used with multi-patterns example by grouping them in a file and using `-f`:

**folder:**

```
$ tree .
.
├── fruit1
├── fruit2
├── fruit3
└── patterns
```

**Content of the files:**

```
$ more *
::::::::::::::
fruit1
::::::::::::::
apple
::::::::::::::
fruit2
::::::::::::::
peach
::::::::::::::
fruit3
::::::::::::::
melon
::::::::::::::
patterns
::::::::::::::
apple
banana
peach
melon
cherry
```

**command:**

```
$ grep -f patterns fruit*
fruit1:apple
fruit2:peach
fruit3:melon
```

You can also sue the different patterns explicitly within the command:

```
$ grep -e apple -e peach -e melon fruit*
fruit1:apple
fruit2:peach
fruit3:melon
```